# password regex validation

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to get one regex that'll do the following:

- Min length's 6 and max. length 8
- No white-space characters
- There is at least one alphabetic character and numeric character
- Not contains Turkish character (ı,ö,ğ,ç,ş,ü)

Exp (valid pass)  ; tester1, TESTER1, 12345a,
     invalid pass ; tester*,tester%

I've this regex : `^.*(?=^.{6,8}$)(?=.*[a-z])((?=.*\d)|(?=.*[A-Z])|(?=.*[\W])).*$`

Can somebody show and teach me how to do this?

Comment: reminds me to http://xkcd.com/936/

Comment: On a slightly unrelated note, such password policies may be very uncomfortable to users. Are there any serious reasons you only want these characters and this particular length?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here we go:

```
^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-zA-Z])[^öÖşŞıİğĞ]{6,8}$
```

```
(?=.*\d)    # must contains one digit from 0-9
(?=.*[a-z]) # must contains one lowercase characters or one uppercase characters
.{6,8}       # length at least 6 characters and maximum of 8
```

`|` = OR example : `(?=.*\d)|(?=.*[A-Z])` = must contains one digit from 0-9 OR must contains one uppercase characters

Thx @Özkan

`[^öÖşŞıİğĞ]` doesnot allow the following characters öÖşŞıİğĞ

You can test it [here](http://derekslager.com/blog/posts/2007/09/a-better-dotnet-regular-expression-tester.ashx)

Comment: `Is somebody show and teach me how to do this?`, You've done the first, how about the second?

Comment: Indent your regex line by four spaces to make it appear as code and e.g. stop hiding the `*`s.

Comment: The OP wants to learn too. An answer on its own isn't much help to a beginner.

Comment: Fixed the formatting, try it now @Dmitry and other downvoter.

Comment: this regex allows turkish character. @GeorgesD How to set regex not contain special characters

Comment: It means that turkish character are between a and z. I try to find a way.

Comment: I edited like this : ^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-zA-Z])[^öÖşŞıİğĞ]{6,8}$  .. Before {6,8} don't necessery full stop character, because it accept one character too. @GeorgesD

Comment: @GeorgesD also you must delete "." from .{6,8}  thank you in advance